# Ruby exception in Logstash config file

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have written a .conf file for logstash but I am unfamiliar with ruby syntax.

I am getting an error -

```
Ruby exception occurred: undefined local variable or method `?' for #
<LogStash::Filters::Ruby:0x2bfd7049>
```

Can someone please point out the mistake?

Here is my code

```
input {
file 
{
path=> "/Users/Work/logs/sample.log"
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
}

filter
{
ruby {
code => "
    fieldarr=event.get('message').split(‘&’)
    for field in fieldarr
        result=field.split('=')
        event.set(result[0],result[1])
    end
    " 
    }
}

output
{
elasticsearch {
codec=>rubydebug
hosts=> ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [`kv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) which does pretty much exactly what you're doing in that code?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with it. I'm not very familiar with logstash. So didn't know in detail about all filters.